# How would I know if a hard drive was jeopardized by a power surge?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, power, mbr, bootsector

I have a hard drive, from which I have rebuilt the MBR and Boot Sector. I was able to recover the data. My client's computer and data were easily visible prior to a power surge in the home. She would like to know if there's evidence that the hard drive was damaged from the power surge.

Is there a set of specific symptoms I can look for to indicate failure from a power surge?

Thanks in advance!

Jared

Comment: I have rebuilt the MBR and Boot Sector. I was able to recover the data.  -- why was this activity needed and how was it done?

Comment: Check the SMART data on the hard drive.

Comment: After checking the SMART data do the following:- 1. Run a drive surface check to find any new bad sectors. 2. Run file system checks on each partition. 3. Run integrity checks on any data-bases on the drive. 4. Compare the latest back-up with the current files and look for major differences.

Comment: I rebuilt the MBR and Boot Sector with TestDisk. The File System is NTFS the partition tables were rebuilt, too. To my knowledge, there are no databases on the hard drive. How would I check for that?

Comment: sfc /scannow    It if detect many bad files that is a bad sign.  We really need to know the make,model, and serial number, and any dates the warranty or date of manufacturer  of the drive.  Using this information a google search for reliability data can be conducted including checking user ratings for the drive on places the like newegg, amazon, and more.  Combining all the data, including SMART, an educated guess can be formed.  The drive might just be getting to old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with any certainty unless you are able to correlate the time of the failure with a power surge with hardware damage, which may be unlikely.

It is also possible that the problem was a software fault induced by the sudden disconnection of electricity, rather then a hardware problem.  If SMART comes up clean and you boot off a Linux distro and run a badblocks test it may tell you more about errors - but be careful as it can also erase data if issued incorrectly.

You may also be able to pull a log from S.M.A.R.T which could correlate the status of the an error with the drive.  I suspect that might be unlikely here though.

Comment: Is there a way to correlate any of these errors (badblocks test or SMART) with a time stamp, which I can then associate with the power surge. I have the exact time of the surge (a picture of a plugged in grandfather clock)

Comment: I doubt it - unless there is something in OS log file.